# Kernel does not execute when N > 32

Tags: cuda, gpu

Here is my kernel (I've generalized it to convey only the salient information):

```
__global__ void kernel(int N1, int N2) {
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  
  if (i < N1 && j < N2)
    printf("[i][j] = [%i][%i]\n", i, j);
}
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(N1, N2); // values of N1 and N2 are arbitrary
int N = N1;
if (N2 > N)
  N = N2;
int numBlocks = (N + 1024 - 1) / 1024;
kernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(N1, N2);
```

Everything is fine when, neither, N1 nor N2 exceed 32. `printf` is invoked N1 * N2 times, as expected.

The moment, either, N1 or N2 exceeds 32 the kernel no longer invokes `printf`. I can't tell if the `if` statement inside the kernel is failing to be called, or if the entire kernel is not being called. My instincts tell me there is something regarding the GPU's architecture that I'm not respecting.

If it matters, my GPU is an RTX 2060 Super. It has a compute capability (CC) of 7.5.

Edit: I realized that the problem occurs when N1 * N2 exceeds 1024, not necessarily when either N1 or N2 exceed 32.

Comment: Why not add a new line:
printf("%i %i", i, j);
just before the if? At least it will tell you if the kernel is being called? Looks like values for i and j just always evaluate the '<' to false in the if statement

Comment: The hardware has a limit of 1024 threads per block